# with a VBA userform, how do you populate a combobox with a different text and value?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am trying to populate a VBA userform combobox with a named range, and I want the text value to display in the combobox for the user to select, but the value I want returned is the cell reference to the initial named range.  That way it would point back to the named range, and if I change that text, it would automatically update all the references I have on the sheet that were entered by the form.

Right now I can get the named range to populate the combobox by iterating through the range, and using an .AddItem to give it the textual value, but then it just dumps that textual value into my spreadsheet, when instead I would like it to have the cell reference from the range that populated it.

Comment: You could create a "StringPair" class with 2 string properties; 1 is the display name and one is the cell reference. Then create a collection of StringPairs and use the display name as key. Then add all keys/display names to combo box, and later use selection to lookup in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create an Array(X,2) X being the number of items in the array. Then you put the String you want to display in Array(1,1) and the data you want in Array(1,2) then simply populate the combo box like normal. When you and use the array to reference which item they choose. They choose item 8, you know it is Array(8,2) If you need more help please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

So, after more research it would seem that I am unable to directly accomplish what I want with the combobox.  I ended up just looping through the range to fill the combobox with the textual values, and then when I submit the form, I looped through the same range of values, checked it if the submitted value matches one from the range of values, and if it does, then return the .Address instead of the .Value, and that gave me the cell reference I was looking for.  Too bad the combobox doesn't work more like a real html select menu, it would have made my life a little easier,  but in the end I was able to make it work, it just isn't as clean as I would have liked.